# scp copy multiple files from remote machine to local machine

Tags: scp

I have the following files in a remote machine:

```
./aerokube/
└── selenoid
    ├── browsers.json
    ├── run.sh
    └── Logger.java
```

I want to copy run.sh and browsers.json from the remote machine to my local machine. I know how to copy a single file from the remote machine:

`scp user@172.100.100.100:/home/aerokube/selenoid/browsers.json .`

But how can I copy both browsers.json and run.sh from the remote machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
scp 'user@172.100.100.100:/home/aerokube/selenoid/{browsers.json,run.sh}' .
```

You need the quotes so that expansion takes place on the remote side. Without it, it will work, but you might have to enter the credentials twice.

Comment: This would likely require that the remote user's login shell understands brace expansions.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
scp -T user@172.100.100.100:"/home/aerokube/selenoid/browsers.json /home/aerokube/selenoid/run.sh" .
```

- In some cases `-T` might not work, so try with and without it.

Comment: I am getting this message: `protocol error: filename does not match request`

Comment: Worked after adding the -T flag!